# Grid field options - file and HTTPS

Tags: grid, http

I have created a file grid field option to store product images in a channel fields. To display one from them on the site I use:

```
    {product_image limit="1"}
            <img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive">
    {/product_image}
```

but it always pulls images as HTTP connection even when I will come to the site as HTTPS.

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you should do is edit your upload preferences with a relative path and not an absolute, that is to say:

```
Server Path to upload directory = /the/actual/server-path/to/my-site/images
URL of Upload Directory = /my-site/images // Note we're not using http://my-site
```

This lets the path be more flexible by letting the browser/location use the current http method.

If you're using a bootstrap you can modify it there if not use the file manager within EE CP